# How to cancel/disable hover and active effects coming from another CSS library?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [Social Buttons for Bootstrap](https://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-social/) to add social buttons on my web site. The file is basically a CSS, which is using Font Awesome and has around 20+ classes defined for various social networks.
Buttons, defined with Bootstrap Social have hover and active effects.

What I want to do is disable hover/active effect, so the buttons would become static, i.e. without any hover/click functionality.

Ideally, I'd like to have some CSS class, say "btn-static", which would cancel style changes coming from hover/active effects.

Is this even possible?

I would like to avoid creating separate CSS class for every social network, or modifying original CSS file. Hoping to add custom class which could cancel hover/active events.

For example, here is the button defined:

```
<span class="btn btn-social btn-facebook">
    <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span>Facebook
</span>
```

I have tried using:

```
.btn-static:active, .btn-static:hover { background-color: none; }
```

and

```
.btn-static:active, .btn-static:hover { background-color: inherit; }
```

But that just makes the button have transparent background. I want it to keep original color. Is it somehow possible to reference the original color in CSS?

**UPDATE #1:** [JSFiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/EVMX/t044se5j/) is available

Comment: Can you give me a working example on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @BlackFire [JSFiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/EVMX/t044se5j/) is available. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a hack:

```
.btn-static {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

[According to Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events), it is well supported. Take a look at the known issues tab on that page, as this won't scale to many other uses.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great help perfect solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, use a more specific selector. For example:

```
#IDofYourFooter .btn:active, #IDofYourFooter .btn:hover, #IDofYourFooter .btn:focus {
   background-color: [whatever] !important;
}
```

If you genuinely cannot come up with a more specific selector, then use `!important` to override CSS that is inline or coming from a third-party source that appears after your styles:

```
.btn:active, .btn:hover, .btn:focus {
   background-color: [whatever] !important;
}
```

See that I added a `:focus` selector in there. Also, using `!important` almost always creates maintenance issues down the road.

Please note that changing styles does not disable links, it just obfuscates them. Make sure these do not live in an `<a href…>`, though if you do that you have no reason to write these styles. If the hover styles are applied outside of an `<a href…>`, then the original source did a poor job or there is script clickability added.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, the problem is I can't hardcode color in CSS, since different social buttons have different colors, and I don't want to end up creating separate class for each of those. I have added [JSFiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/EVMX/t044se5j/), hope it will make more sense now

Comment: Ah. I posted an additional answer as it wasn't really appropriate as a comment here since it is a totally different approach.